# AJAX - First Time Refresh using Handlebars

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

The code below is attempting to first display previous comments, and then on submit button click, refresh by showing the newer comment.

The second AJax call works fine. But the first Ajax call does nothing ('/show' is a valid request - and the first call '/comment' calls '/show')

Here is my code snippet:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var source   = $("#login_template");
        var srcHTML =source.html();
        var login_template = Handlebars.compile(srcHTML);
        source   = $("#comment_template");
        srcHTML =source.html();
        var comment_template = Handlebars.compile(srcHTML);
        // First time call to server to get the comments
        $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
            type: "post",
            url: "/show", 
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) 
            {
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              var html = login_template(data);
              $("#login_content").html(html);
              html = comment_template(data);
              $("#comment_content").html(html);
            }
         });        

        $("#comment_button").click(function(event) {
          $.ajax({ // ajax call to send comment to server and refresh with newer comment
            type: "post",
            url: "/comment", 
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data:  JSON.stringify(
                {
                  'source' : source.value,
                  'comment': comment.value,
                }),
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) 
            {
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              var html = login_template(data);
              $("#login_content").html(html);
              html = comment_template(data);
              $("#comment_content").html(html);
            }
         });        
      });
   });
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did console.log/alert within success block and it does not seem to get there.
As you can see above, both ajax functions pretty much the same. The first one makes server call 'show' and the second one makes server call 'comment' which in turn redirects to server call 'show' after processing 'comment'. The second ajax call works fine.

Here is my Handlebar Template code:

```
 <script id="login_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          logout={{logout}}
          login={{login}}
          {{#if user}}
            {{user.nickname}}!  
            [<a href="{{logout}}"><b>sign out</b></a>]
          {{else}}
            Guest  
            [<a href="{{login}}"><b>sign in</b></a>]
          {{/if}}
    </script>

    <script id ="comment_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
        <h2>Top 10 Most Recent Guestbook Entries</h2>
          no of greetings {{greetings.length}}
          {{#each greetings}}
             greetings!
            <br>
              <small>[<i>{{date.ctime}}</i>]</small>
              <b>
              {{#if author }}
                <code>{{author.nickname}}</code>
              {{else}}
                <i>anonymous</i>
              {{/if}}
              </b>
              wrote:
              {{comment}}
          {{/each}}
    </script>
```

Here is my DOM elements within HTML body:

```
  <div id="login_content"></div>
  <div id="comment_content"></div>
```

And here is the server code:

```
class ShowComment(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        greetings = Greeting.all().order('-date').fetch(10)
        results = {
            'user':      user,
            'greetings': greetings,
            'login':     users.create_login_url(self.request.uri),
            'logout':    users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri),
        }
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.out.write( JSONUtils.GqlEncoder().encode(results) )

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    Jguest_data = json.loads(self.request.body) 
    greeting = Greeting()
    for gb_name,gb_comment in Jguest_data.iteritems():

        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
           greeting.author = user
        greeting.content = gb_comment
        greeting.put()
        self.redirect('/show')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                              ('/comment', Guestbook),
                              ('/show',ShowComment)
                               ],
                              debug=True)
```

**Thanks a mil.**